# What can I do about duplicate data in Apple Health?

Tags: ios, bug, health.app, health-kit

Recently (and not tied to any iOS or app update) Apple Health has doubled all the steps it has recorded. This occurred literally overnight, so that now for every day, as far back as I've looked, all the steps recorded are twice what they were (correctly) previously. Since this occurred suddenly and retroactively, and without any updates taking place to Apple Health, iOS, or (as far as I can tell) any apps that share steps, it appears to be a bug in Apple Health itself.

What can I do about this duplication of step data in Apple Health? How do I reset or correct such discrepancies?

Comment: Do you synchronize your iPhone with your iCloud storage?

Comment: @danielAzuelos How would that matter? HK data stays on the phone.

Comment: That “could” matter because a synchronization mechanism acting both ways is a usual suspect to create duplicates.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Except that HK is not synced. What am I missing in your logic?